# Updating by index in an multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy to tally a lot of values across many large arrays, and keep track of which positions the maximum values appear in.

In particular, imagine I have a 'counts' array:

```
data = numpy.array([[ 5, 10, 3],
                    [ 6, 9, 12],
                    [13, 3,  9],
                    [ 9, 3,  1],
                    ...
                    ])
counts = numpy.zeros(data.shape, dtype=numpy.int)
```

`data` is going to change a lot, but I want 'counts' to reflect the number of times the max has appeared in each position:

```
max_value_indices = numpy.argmax(data, axis=1)
# this is now [1, 2, 0, 0, ...] representing the positions of 10, 12, 13 and 9, respectively.
```

From what I understand of broadcasting in numpy, I should be able to say:

```
counts[max_value_indices] += 1
```

What I expect is the array to be updated:

```
[[0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0],
 ...
]
```

But instead this increments ALL the values in `counts` giving me:

```
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 ...
]
```

I also though perhaps if I transformed max_value_indices to a 100x1 array, it might work:

```
counts[max_value_indices[:,numpy.newaxis]] += 1
```

but this has effect of updating just the elements in positions 0, 1, and 2:

```
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0],
 ...
]
```

I'm also happy to turn the indices array into an array of 0's and 1's, and then add it to the `counts` array each time, but I'm not sure how to construct that.

Comment: I think you must mean `argmax()` instead of `max()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use so-called [advanced integer indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer) (aka [Multidimensional list-of-locations indexing](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Indexing#head-4775c8118fff07ae55b6e3b95c3b48e540160fc2)):

```
In [24]: counts[np.arange(data.shape[0]), 
                np.argmax(data, axis=1)] += 1

In [25]: counts
Out[25]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

The first array, `np.arange(data.shape[0])` specifies the row. The second array, `np.argmax(data, axis=1)` specifies the column.